# Reduction of Elliptic Integrals

Tags: analysis, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to solve exercises from Mathematical Analysis I by Zorich and I am stuck on a problem about reduction of quartic polynomials:

A fourth-degree polynomial $ax ^ 4 + b x ^ 3 \ldots + e$ can be rearded as a product $a (x ^ 2 + p_1 x + q_1) (x ^ 2 + p_2 x + q_2)$ and can always be brought into the form $\frac{(M_1 + N_1t) (M_2 + N_2t)}{(\gamma t + 1) ^ 2}$ by a substitution $x = \frac{\alpha t + \beta}{\gamma t + 1}$.

I guess the part I do not understand is if we make the substitution specified in the problem, then the degree of $t$ in the resulting numerator and denominator should be the same right? How come that the result is in the desired form?

Comment: I am sorry for a typo! It should be "regarded" in the statement of the problem.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I found a source online that is super helpful in understanding elliptic integrals but does not follow the thread in the book. I guess I will just go with this.

Comment: The link is https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.chmm/1428686948

Comment: This statement is incorrect. The correct version should be $\frac{(M_1 + N_1 t ^ 2)(M_2 + N_2 t ^ 2)}{(\gamma t + 1) ^ 4}$.